# What book does this appendix on formal group laws belong to?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, formal-groups

Can you please identify the book that the appendix https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/mybooks/ravenelA2.pdf belongs to?

This chapter is on universal formal group laws and strict isomorphisms.

I am not sure about whether it is a book or series of class notes but from the above link it seems that it should be a book.

Please help me to identify it.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=19GFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA339&lpg=PA339&dq=%22Universal+Formal+Group+Laws+and+Strict+Isomorphisms%22&source=bl&ots=Jza2NIVcik&sig=ACfU3U05wj7M13v8bJZ9u4Xmev3l9AZh7g&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9-Yriwa7nAhUWIzQIHRB_CkIQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Universal%20Formal%20Group%20Laws%20and%20Strict%20Isomorphisms%22&f=false

Comment: @robjohn, thank you

Comment: Please make your titles more descriptive, and please don't use \text for emphasis in math mode.

Comment: @KReiser, thank you for editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres By Douglas C. Ravenel

Comment: thank you very much